# Как сделать чтобы div содержащий кнопку был всегда по центру при любом разрешении экрана?

Tags: html, css, css3

Добрый день! Есть `div` на странице, который содержит кнопку:

```css
a.green_button.ok {
    padding-left: 30px;
    background: url(/img/green_button_ok.png) no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="fastorder" align="center"><a href="/ajax/callback.php" class="green_button ok order_call fancybox-form fancybox.ajax">Быстрый заказ</a> </div>
```

Как сделать чтобы `div` содержащий кнопку был всегда по центру при любом разрешении экрана? Сейчас если смотреть на планшете или на телефоне кнопка сдвигается вправо, как сделать чтобы она всегда оставалась по центру?

Comment: А зачем тут vertial-align, padding-left и position:absolute? Если их убрать, то всё встаёт как раз по центру

Comment: если убрать position:absolute нет возможности, тогда так https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/74ej5xzm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы прописали `position: absolute;`

Нужно либо убрать `position: absolute;` либо сдвинуть:

**1 способ,** когда известна ширина. Как бы этот способ не ругали, у него лучше кроссбраузерность.

```css
a.green_button.ok {
    
    background: url(/img/green_button_ok.png) no-repeat;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="fastorder" align="center"><a href="/ajax/callback.php" class="green_button ok order_call fancybox-form fancybox.ajax">Быстрый заказ</a> </div>
```

**2 способ**, когда не известна ширина. Поддержка браузерами [83% (по России)](http://caniuse.com/#search=translateX)

```css
a.green_button.ok {
    
    background: url(/img/green_button_ok.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%)
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="fastorder" align="center"><a href="/ajax/callback.php" class="green_button ok order_call fancybox-form fancybox.ajax">Быстрый заказ</a> </div>
```

**3 способ**, когда нужно по центру страницы, а не блока.

```css
a.green_button.ok {
    
    background: url(/img/green_button_ok.png) no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="fastorder" align="center"><a href="/ajax/callback.php" class="green_button ok order_call fancybox-form fancybox.ajax">Быстрый заказ</a> </div>
```

Comment: У меня она не по центру: http://joxi.ru/Vm63vE6iD3Vq92   Более того скажу, что отрицательные маржины - рак 2017-го года в css.

Comment: Ахахах, сделал не -30px, а -50px. Очень классное решение :D Для всех кнопок таким заниматься будешь?